# Multiple Git Fix Up Commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I would like to make a `fixup` commit against a previous commit.
However that commit has already had a `fixup` commit made against it for another reason.

Should I make my new fixup against the last fixup commit, or can I still fixup against the original commit, essentially meaning I have 1 original commit and 2 fixup commits.

Comment: Either method works fine, so use whichever you personally prefer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do either it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Situation you mentioned is similar to this one:

```
pick b7d9adb99 A
fixup 08bcd9b3d fixup for A
fixup 76014576b fixup for A
fixup 58ab94324 fixup for A
```

or this one:

```
pick b7d9adb99 A
fixup 08bcd9b3d fixup for b7d9adb99
fixup 76014576b fixup for 08bcd9b3d 
fixup 58ab94324 fixup for 76014576b
```

So effectively it does not matter if you make fixup to 'main' commit or make 'fixup to fixup'. As a result, 'main' commit (in my case `b7d9adb99`) will include all of the fixup-changes and change its hash (in my case into `29074c0ec`).